# How do I best implement generics within structs/traits, regular variable declarations, and functions?

Tags: generics, rust

So building a little project to learn Rust and was wondering what the best way would be to define a vector with a hashmap

The way to data is going to be structured in the end is as follows:

```json
  [
      {
          id: "USER_ID",
          firstname: "First Name",
          lastname: "Last Name",
          email: "Email",
          errors: [ { type: "...", message: "cannot update user" } ],
      }
  ]
```

So I was thinking I'd write out my project as follows

src/parser.rs

```rust
pub struct Parser<T> {
   pub parsed_log: Vec<HashMap<String, T>>,
}

// pub trait ReturnProperties {
//    fn return_parsed_logs(&self) -> Vec<HashMap<String, T>>;
// }

impl<T: Clone> Parser<T> {
   /// handle upsert will parse the upsert lines into a users vector
   /// it will also match the errors with the user id
   
   // will implement later
   //pub fn handle_upsert(...) {}

   pub fn return_parsed_logs(self) -> Vec<HashMap<String, T, RandomState>> {
      self.parsed_log.to_vec()
   }
}
```

src/main.rs

```rust
fn main() {
    // why does this keep returning
    // cannot find type `T` in this scope??
    let log_parser: parser::Parser<T> = Parser {
        parsed_log: vec![]
    };
}
```

Am I doing this all wrong? I feel like trying to force rust to behave like an OOP language (where i came from) but it's not having it. Any pointers? What did I get totally wrong here?

Comment: try to give `T` a valid type, e.g. `parsed_log: Vec::<HashMap<String, String>>::new()`

Comment: generics are replaced by valid types during compile. refer to [Performance of Code Using Generics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-01-syntax.html)

Comment: I can't understand what the (JSON?) data has to do with the code. Are you writing a parser for this data format? What is `T` for?

Comment: The JSON data is what would have been parsed out of a log file. I was under the assumption the rust complier would infer the types I needed so long as I used T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> // why does this keep returning
> // cannot find type `T` in this scope??
> let log_parser: parser::Parser<T> = Parser {
>     parsed_log: vec![]
> };
> ```

Because there's no type `T` in this scope? When you *declare* a type, the `T` is a *placeholder* (which is declared as such, that's what e.g. the `<T: Clone>` does before the typename in the `impl` block), but when you're *using* the type you need to provide either an actual thing, or a type which was declared somewhere in scope (usually on the function such that the caller can provide that type).

Note that you can often ask Rust to infer types e.g. sometimes you will see

```
let foo: Vec<_> = bar.collect();
```

this lets rustc know you want to collect() to a `Vec`, but lets it infer the item type (because it's unambiguous).

Here however there's nothing to constrain `T`, no information rustc can use to decide what it could or would be.

Though I think your entire thinking is mistaken: in Rust, a generic `T` will be replaced by a single concrete type. But that's not what the initial structure shows, 4 of the items map to strings, but the 5th maps to an array of sub-structures. That won't fit into a `T`, the keys have completely different values. Why are your even using a `HashMap` and generics for this, why not a struct or enum?

Comment: Interesting, so @Masklinn you suggest I a struct and maybe enums ?

Comment: Yes, and something like Serde for the (de)serialisation of the log entries. At least given the bit you show here I think it it would make  sense to have a static structure (or an enum with a variant for errors and one for successes, you don't really describe your "schema").

Comment: Yeah, I'm still trying to determine how it will look right now.

I have serde so +1 for me :) I did something right ahaha.